# Why are my SQL queries yielding a different order?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, derby

I have a table like this:

```
Name     Seats
101      60
102      40
202      100
201      20
```

None of the data can be null, so each name of a room will have an attributed number of seats to it. Now here's my problem:

When I run this SQL Query:

```
select name from rooms
```

I get this output:

```
Name
101      
102      
201      
202
```

When I run this SQL Query:

```
select seats from rooms
```

I get this output:

```
Name
60
40
100
20
```

Notice in my first query `select name from rooms`, the order of the values in the tables changes, while in my second query, when I'm going for the seats, the order remains enact. Why is this the case?

How can I fix my SQL query so it doesn't reorder the names of my rooms?

I'd like it to maintain order and output this:

```
Name    
101      
102      
202      
201
```

Comment: The order of the rows returned by a SELECT statement without an ORDER BY clause is undefined.

Comment: @forpas I see, so I guess I was just lucky all this time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  SQL results sets are *unordered*, unless there is an explicit `ORDER BY` corresponding to the outermost `SELECT`.

Period.

If you don't have an `ORDER BY`, you should have no expectations on the ordering of the results.  The ordering can change from one run to another.

And, even if you have an `ORDER BY`, if you have ties (i.e. keys with the same values), then they can be ordered arbitrarily from one run to the next.

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooh so I was just lucky all this time then

Comment: any idea how to make both of these queries line up in the same order? I'm not sure what I can order by to make them match up

Comment: @JohnnyRobertson . . . Include an `order by`, such as `order by name`.

Comment: oh yea you're right i see now, thank you!

Comment: @JohnnyRobertson Yes, you were lucky. Just make sure you explicitly ask for the ordering when you need it.

Comment: @TheImpaler will definitely do that! thanks for the advice. to think I've been doing SQL for over a month now and never encountered this problem is just so lucky. guess I shoulda paid more attention to the fundamentals

Answer (score 2):

Likely the `select name` query is reading only an index (this is called a covered query), not the table itself, producing a different order.  But the principle is that you should never rely on any particular order except to the extent that it is specified by the order by clause of the outermost query.

Comment: yea it seemed like it was ordering it in acesnding order 101->102->201->202